# How to output a massive file with PHP without running out of memory

Tags: php

I have the code below to output a big file, but it's falling over because PHP's memory use seems to grow and grow as the file is read:

```
  <?php
  // various header() calls etc.
  $stream = fopen($tarfile,'r');
  ob_end_flush();
  while (!feof($stream)) {
    $buf = fread($stream, 4096);
    print $buf;
    flush();
    unset($buf);
    $aa_usage = memory_get_usage(TRUE); // ← this keeps going up!
  }
  fclose($stream);
```

I had thought that by the combination of flush and unset the additional memory use would be limited to the 4k buffer, but I'm clearly wrong.

Comment: Why not simply use [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)?

Comment: Try `ob_flush();` and `flush();` together.

Comment: If you only want to output it so you can use its content you can use `require_once 'filename.php';` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: This helped me a lot when using `readStream` with Flysystem. Hopefully this comment will enable Google to find this question when someone else searches for Flysystem in this context. The example from your question actually worked for me almost as-is, replacing `$tarfile` with the `readStream` resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is to output the content of a file then the right tool to do it is the PHP function [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). Replace all the code you posted with:

```
readfile($tarfile);
```

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#refsect1-function.readfile-notes) says:

> **Note:**
>
> `readfile()` will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with [`ob_get_level()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php).

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes you miss the obvious things, eh?! Although I still would like to understand what's wrong with the code above.

Comment: I ran your code and the value of `$aa_usage` doesn't change. It is `2097152` on PHP 7, `786432` on PHP 5.3 and `262144` on PHP 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6. I used a file of 43 MB for testing with bare CLI PHP.

Comment: hmmm, interesting, thanks. My env is Drupal 7, although I thought I would have disabled any caching with the ob_end_clean() call... Mysterious!

Answer (score 0):

You can try load only as much data as you need first, and if you load more data use the function: [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)

Comment: that's what the code does - loads 4KB at a time. (no need for fseek - that's done automatically as part of the read) It's just that PHP seems to keep it around longer than I need it, so each read increases memory use.